# Can't log into facebook using sample apps

Tags: android, facebook

I'm unable to login to any of the facebook sample apps. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I've complete all the steps on the facebook developers website (I think).

I've added my key hash to the developer's page and logged into my phone.

When I run the hackbook sample app, I get the error : Invalid access token on the screen.

i'm fairly new to facebook programming, so any answers would help.

Comment: Check the log. You should be able to find more info about the error that way.

Comment: The log hasn't thrown any warnings, exceptions or errors at me. What does it mean by invalid access token.